# MD5 hash of file changes after comitting, deleting and fetching from git

Tags: python, git, hash, md5

If one were to do the following:

```py
def hashmdfive(filename):
    """Generate the md5 checksum."""
    hasher = hashlib.md5()
    with open(filename, "rb") as afile:
        buf = afile.read()
        hasher.update(buf)
    return hasher.hexdigest()
```

1. make a file (e.g. `test.txt`) with some content.
2. create hash of file by running hashmdfive above.
3. committing and pushing to a remote git repo
4. delete local file.
5. fetching `test.txt` from remote
6. create new hash of file by running hashmdfive above.

THE HASHES ARE DIFFERENT. Does anyone know why that is the case?

Comment: Have you taken a look at line ending ? Are they consistent ? Some pipelines autoformat `CR LF` to `LF`

Comment: Just as a note, MD5 is completely useless for pretty much all purposes these days.  Try SHA-256 or BLAKE2b instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are running on Windows, [git's autocrlf feature](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) can be the cause of a digest changing:

This will show you the current value:
`git config --global core.autocrlf`

Anything other than "False" can result in the behavior you are observing.